# Meaning of - "Miss the wrong period and it won't be the principal you have to see. "

Tags: meaning, phrases

I saw this in a movie and I'm trying to figure out the meaning. It looks like it says that if you miss the wrong class you won't be sent to the principal. I'm not sure whether I'm correct. Any help with clarification of the meaning would be much appreciated.

Its from the movie *Lean on Me* (1989) starring Morgan Freeman, and it's written on a school door.

Comment: Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere – Help Center](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/)

Comment: @user7841468 Also, you should place all the pertinent information within the body of your question, not in comments. I will do that for you.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: @MetaEd That covers neither of the two reasons I often respond using a 'comment'. These are (a) seeking to help OP without endorsing what I consider to be a question that should be close-voted; (b) offering what I consider to be a reasonable attempt at a response where either I'm not fully convinced myself or can find no supporting references. And while there have been opinions voiced that this practice is not in accordance with site policy, there have been other opinions voiced saying that it is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a **teen pregnancy prevention** poster which the OP saw in the movie called [Lean on Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_on_Me_(film)), made in 1989 and starring Morgan Freeman. The caption which lies beneath makes the message very clear.

> Get pregnant and your future could go right out the door.

The word *period* also refers to a woman's menstrual cycle, when a young woman misses her period she is likely to be pregnant.

[image]

I wouldn't call any of the wording on the poster a pun, it's not meant to be funny, it's a serious message aimed at preventing unplanned pregnancies among teens.

It's saying to female teenagers: if you thought that seeing the Principal was serious, seeing a doctor (or a gynecologist) when you're still a student and pregnant is worse.

This is also a play on the word *door*; in the image we see a door leading to a gynecologist clinic, not the office of a Highschool principal.  In the caption, the word "door" is used in its figurative sense.

As further proof that this is the same poster used in the movie, please see the movie screenshot below

[image: Morgan Freeman entering a classroom]

Comment: Completely wrong interpretation of the question. See answer above.

Comment: @Andre I sympathize that you feel you are being trolled but... read the caption at the bottom of the poster. Until I found the image, it was possible, possible but highly unlikely, that someone could interpret period as meaning "lesson" but two images... the word "pregnant" the gynecologist door... and there were at least three users (whose comments are deleted) that were telling you that you had misinterpreted it. You had all the time to edit, and fix it. You didn't want to.

Comment: This is clearly the right answer, but, IMHO, there are a couple of points that you didn’t make clearly enough: (1) “***Missing*** your period” is the standard phrase for not menstruating on schedule, so the pun hinges specifically on the juxtaposition of the words “miss” and “period”. (2) “… it won’t be the principal you’ll have to see” ties directly into the identification of the OB/GYN as the person you’ll have to see, and [the idiom of “seeing” a doctor](http://www.workjoke.com/doctors-jokes.html#365). I consider the “door” pun to be less relevant, since it wasn’t mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Websters defines "pun" as *the **usually** humorous use of a word in such a way as to suggest two or more of its meanings or the meaning of another word similar in sound*.  The poster is most definitely "playing" on the fact that there are two distinctly different meanings of "period" being referenced.

Comment: @HotLicks  Yes, I understand what "pun" means but the poster was not meant to be funny. It's a clever play on words. It's not a joke. At least,  I never interpreted it as a joke, I never thought it was supposed to be amusing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - A "pun" is, first and foremost, a play on words.  It does not need to be "funny" in the ROTFL sense.

Comment: @HotLicks no, you're right there. Puns very often make listeners *groan* and cringe. A bit like a bad dad's joke. Look, Scott also used "pun" in his comments, I'm disputing that the message was meant to be humorous.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Humor is in the eye of the beholder, and especially so for puns.

Answer (score 1):

[Period](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/period):

> 6 a : a portion of time determined by some recurring phenomenon
>
> b (1) : the interval of time required for a cyclic motion or phenomenon to
> complete a cycle and begin to repeat itself
>
> (2) : a number k that does
> not change the value of a periodic function f when added to the
> independent variable; especially : the smallest such number
>
> c : a
> **single cyclic occurrence of menstruation**

The poster was clearly employing a pun on the word "period", conflating a class "period" in a school with "period" meaning menstruation.